# Should SE sites be a little more holistic?

Tags: feature-request, questions, stack-exchange, off-topic, scope

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52852/why-do-all-stack-exchange-sites-have-to-be-on-such-focused-topics) is closely related, but I don't think it's a dupe. The OP asks why SE sites have to be so focused, but then seems to propose that there be one master website under which all SE topics are a subset. I don't agree with that. But I do think that SE sites are a little too narrowly focused. I can accept that:

> "programming related" is not narrow at all. There are discussions on things ranging from LOGO turtles to regexes to worpress to iphone development to functional programming, etc. Very wide - not narrow.
>
> ~ tim, commenting on [the linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52852/why-do-all-stack-exchange-sites-have-to-be-on-such-focused-topics).

So I concede that programming requires more than one website. But take websites like [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=blog). This would be a great opportunity to have a website on blogging in general, or for people who use Blogger or custom websites to do blogging, but that is specifically disallowed:

> Note that we do not handle questions:
>
> - not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context):
>
>   - blogging and managing sites in general - try Pro Webmasters
>
> ~ Excerpt from WordPress Help Centre

Or [MathEducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). Why not have a site for educators in general? And what about [Biblical Hermaneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)? Hermaneutics and philology in general are good fields, but this site is for the Bible only. And why are there so many websites about one specific technology or software, such as Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Tor, Joomla, Craft CMS, Tridion, SharePoint, etc.? Could these not be amalgamated into several larger websites like Electrical Engineering, StackOverflow, or just a dedicated site for technologies that aren't Apple, Android or Windows?

Again, I'm not proposing there should be some master website differentiating all topics with tags. But I think that there are certain websites where a broader scope would be beneficial, because good questions (e.g. about the Blogger platform, teaching History, or interpretation of Plato's *The Republic*,) that would fit neatly into the same field are disallowed from the website.

Comment: Did you look at how area 51 and site proposals work?

Comment: I did. What did I miss?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps some psychology of how communities work?

Answer (score 7):

With the [site proposal process](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), sites are created by people proposing them and other supporting the proposal.

There isn't a general educators site, because it was either not proposed or the proposal did not gain enough support.

The sites that do exist have come to be because they did gain support and have shown that there is a community around them.

Proposals that are too broad in scope tend to be overly vague and not gain much support (a not sure what's this about reaction will not end up with many people giving it their support). A clearly focused proposal, however, will be clear for people to either support or not.

---

And that's the point. Communities. Not topics. Not sites. Communities.

We have several different CMS communities - they are separate, distinct communities that have grown up grass roots.

Sure, these **could**, technically, be amalgamated but at a cost to the communities and the community feelings. Giving people their own place is a powerful thing, and taking it away can break communities up.

If they work, why do that?

Comment: Okay, I suppose you make a powerful argument for "don't fix what isn't broken." But I think that there's a fine balance between overvague holism and unhelpful specificity, and I still think one or two websites go too far to the right - particularly WordPress. I find it very strange that the community created a website for one specific blogging platform and not blogging in general.

Comment: @Leo - it isn't a site about blogging. It is a technical site about developing WordPress sites.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Should've read the Help Centre more carefully.

Comment: That's true for the other CMS sites too ;)