# Should there a proposal for a lost question section for Area 51, where they can be connected and to taken to a new proposal for a site?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, off-topic

**TL;DR:** This is not a "dump and go" site for people that don't have a place for their questions, but *almost* a reverse Area 51 process. This is for high-quality lost questions to find the right site proposal that they deserve, not get stuck on an unsuitable site.

---

Should there be a mini-site for questions that don't currently fit in anywhere (don't have a site for the topic) in the Stack Exchange Network?

### Introduction:

Perhaps as an extra-bit for Area 51, where any well-introduced user, when they have already had a good search around for where a question should go, and perhaps asked in Meta, can post a question. There the question could be housed, linked to a few tags, and with experienced users' help could improve the wording of this question.

Meanwhile, anyone on the main section of Area 51, could request to link either the whole tag (though a proposed site's question on the tag page), or the individual question (through an answer) easily to a proposal, and the question's creator will be notified that there might be a site for them, so that any Area 51 proposal would get a small boost.

I have come up with some questions that don't fit in the network and I don't want them to remain unasked / unanswered due to having nowhere to go. Similarly, I find creating a proposal in Area 51 incredibly challenging because although example question titles for an individual site are created during definition phase, creating a proposal from example questions is much harder. If there is a site for questions with the following features and restrictions, I think that it would be a good **temporary** home for lost questions and would not devolve into our hyphenated pals.

### Proposed features/restrictions:

- Only association bonus (or higher network reputation, consensus pending) users can ask questions, since they have a view of good question layout.
- "Where should question x go?", questions should be preferably asked before going here, to avoid mass-closing of questions on the minisite. However, this site is for when the answer is: "this is a good question, and it should really have a place on this site, but there isn't anywhere at all". Instead of turning users away, or encouraging them to create a proposal (which is *hard*, especially when trying to define a relatively broad site for a very few questions that share a narrow scope), they could use this site.
- Finding the answer to the question, is finding an Area 51 site for the question in order to get a good quality answer for the question, once there are enough professionals or dedicated enthusiasts to answer it.
- Accepting an answer, is accepting that the proposed site fits the question's target audience, and should be intergrated into the Area 51 proposal (much like questions about a proposal are automatically added to the proposal page).
- Tags follow the normal guidelines, and perhaps have higher rep creation requirements to avoid one tag per question and similar issues.
- Once a tag is big enough for its own site, it will be considered in meta along with the standard proposal system, then *eventually* mass movals combined with a super-burnination-redirect system, some builtin moderator system, once the proposal enters Private Beta.
- Area 51 proposals could have a section of the page with a small box, "Your proposal might already have a few more questions:". This could start at the middle of the definition phase, or maybe at the commit to avoid the initial purpose of the site being squashed by the influx. The question concerned can be be re-worded to fit the proposed site better while keeping the original purpose.
- The original question creator will be notified of an "answer" to their question (a place where the question could go), and can then they can help the proposal with their input.
- Private betas on the topic will have these questions migrated there. Users will be encouraged to use the site, to match up potentially active users with their interest's site. This also gives new sites good questions which they can further fine-tune to the site's needs.
- All questions that are now on-topic for an existing site will be considered for migration, and tags on that topic will be heavily, if not forceably discouraged, offering users the chance to move their question over to a Private/Public Beta or graduated site if they or others agree that it is the right place for the question.

If you think that the idea can be improved, feel free to suggest improvements, or post reasons why / why not.

Comment: I am *not* a sock! See my profile for proof...

Comment: @JasonC Different accounts, different people. We do know each other though. I'm trying to remain unbiased - I did not directly access this page, rather browsed [meta.se] and came across the question. I suggested an edit to it because I saw improvements that could be made. The names are a coincidence - if I were setting up a sock network (BIG if - I won't do this) I would not make it so obvious.

Comment: Removing idea for tagless queue as it encourages many tags for no gain...

Comment: I'm really struggling with understanding how this would be beneficial to the entity that is SE. This sounds like a dumping ground for bad questions and a site that would be too broad and also would take away from sites that do exist. If everything is on topic, then it means that it could attract any question that might actually have a home. There are also some *types* of questions that will never have a home here. SE isn't here to satisfy every question. Who are the experts? The number one rule of SE is that sites have to have a group of experts!

Comment: @Catija Those sort of bad questions would be closed, there still will be a strong enforcement of the q and a format, as defined by the community already countless times. Too broad would still exist, along with all other close reasons. Only high-rep users would be allowed anyway (maybe higher than association bonus). Questions that already have a site would not be on-topic on the existing site. Timezone / sleep limitations mean somebody else may need to work on this idea for me.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Who are you and what have you done with wizzwizz3??

Comment: @Catja As now clarified this is **no** site for terrible questions. I'm just afraid that this proposal will collapse for its similarities with bad question dumps.

Comment: @JasonC That is a long story for another time...

Comment: @JasonC You're the first person to bring that up on the network. wizzwizz3 was my old account name on a different site before the account name stopped working during login migration - I'm thinking of using it as an _actual_ sockpuppet (for testing chatbots).

Comment: So of the *many* issues with this proposal, one of the major ones is: What do you do when enough questions about a particular "off-topic" subject have been asked that you essentially have enough material to post a new site? What do you do with all that content? Also, this essentially creates a "path of least resistance" for questions that don't have a site to call home, relative to a proper Area 51 proposal, which seems like it would only reduce the effort put in to constructing and supporting a proposal, polishing it off, posting good examples, and damage that process in general.

Comment: 100 rep is **NOT** a "high rep user". "On topic elsewhere" has **never** been a reason to close a question on a site and I don't see it being very welcoming to people to have a site where so many questions are closed. It also makes the site into a "where do I ask this" site... which MSE already is. It also means that, instead of adding to our ecosystem of sites by proposing a new site, people just chuck it on this one and go.

Comment: @Catija It doesn't neccesarily have to be a Q&A site on that question; just  a place where that question can wait to go. Discussions could be limited to where that question could go. The reputation required is subject to change. High-rep users will not use it for "where do I ask this", as they would already know as well as being familiar with how the site works.

Comment: Here is off topic question: when wizzwizz6 will arrive?

Comment: This site will not be a standard Q&A site, like mSE or Discuss Area51 isn't.

Comment: I need to leave due to generic time zone constraints, e.g. work, school, sleep, so feel free to improve the proposal and continue to leave constructive comments.

Comment: Wait... so this isn't a Q&A site? The questions wouldn't be answered, only asked? Isn't that what A51 **is**? Also, I contest that having a lot of rep on a site does not mean you know the subjectmatter of all 100+sites on the network... or whether they even exist at all. The wide variety of re-suggested topics that are closed as duplicate proposals  on A51 proves that...

Comment: @Catija Maybe it's just an A site, where you can post answers to questions nobody knew they had.

Comment: Who exactly is the expert audience that will answer all of these random questions that don't fit into any other site? Sites aren't "topics" - SE sites are communities. It is really hard to get a proposal off the ground, but that's just because it's really hard to build a community, even when you aren't starting completely from scratch. You can't just group random questions from random people, add some technology and expect it to become a community. Sorry, that sounds harsher than I meant it to be, but I'm in a hurry. If I add smilies would that help or hurt? :)

Comment: Such a site exists. It's called Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: [Why do all Stack Exchange sites have to be on such focused topics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52852/21960)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a catch-all place on the Stack Exchange network where one can post any question that does not obviously belong to the Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83986/21960)

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. Question should now fully explain my idea...

Comment: @Catija Yes, it is what Area 51 is for, which is why it should idealy sit as a mini-site beside it, or the questions that need matching to proposals are an intergrated feature. I would have suggested it as an Area 51 proposal or DiscussArea51 but thought of it more as a feature request. The rep is a thing that I couldn't decide upon myself as it is a hard thing to figure out, and I suppose ironicly users with higher rep should decide how high the rep must be, or what other measures should be in place.

Comment: @JasonC No, it's just a Q site, where you can post questions for topics nobody knew they had.

Comment: @ColleenV Nobody's answering them until a community exists. The questions are posted, and similar questions will be grouped and ultimately become an Area 51 proposal. The experts for this site already exist in Area 51.

Comment: @ale I know, and I kind of always knew that the first draft of my idea would be mistaken for Yahoo! Answers (and a duplicate of that question posted there). I've tried to clear things up.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Hopefully, I've re-worded my question to fix my clarity...

Comment: I doubt that a successful community will spontaneously evolve from a random group of people with similar questions. I still wonder who the experts will be that are interested in an arbitrary grouping of questions. Even though questions are a large part of a proposal, they aren't at the core of a site - people are. A site needs champions who are passionate about its success and folks that have more than one question to ask. Maybe I would change my mind after seeing the collected questions though. I'm having a hard time imagining what they could be.

Comment: @ColleenV The groups of questions wouldn't make there own site on their own, the beta sites would still go through the normal Area 51 process, where passionate people join in. But if all of these questions were improved in quality as if they were already in their own Beta site, the enthusiasts and experts would be encouraged to propose the site by being enticed by the sheer quality of the questions, and others will join in faster by seeing the good questions as an example of what the site could be at it's best.

Comment: I understand that good quality questions do not make a site on its own, but it has almost always been good quality questions that aid good quality answers, and if a private beta starts off with some perfectly formatted template questions, it will encourage new experts to join the SE network, and more experts already on the SE network to give the closed beta a try.

Comment: This question may have been duplicate-like before, but this is a very specialized and targeted feature request: This is **not** a place that makes the All department to solve an x question, this is for questions that have been rejected by the Existing departments, but are good questions and should in an ideal world have a home on SE.  **But not to get answered by any person yet, but the question is a normal style body of a question, but the A is showing the asker to the proposal for the department specialized in answering their sort of question.**

Comment: @wizzwizz2 I've tentatively voted to reopen on those grounds. Still, question: With your bold text in mind, how is this any different from Area 51 and its example question area, which already exists? Why would you put essentially an example question on this hypothetical site instead of making an actual site proposal on Area 51 and posting it there (which, btw, is *really* easy)? Also, do you really see use in a site where "Belongs on an *existing* Area 51 proposal" is going to be a legitimate, and likely well-used, close reason?

Comment: @JasonC It has a section, along with existing example questions, for questions that don't yet have a proposal for them.  It belonging on an existing Area 51 proposal is going to be an answer, not a close, and accepting the answer is accepting integration into an area 51 proposal.

Comment: @JasonC My reasoning behind this is that a proposal can easily be too broad, or too narrow / localized on creation, but with other "lost" questions in mind, they can get a better idea of the proposal that the community needs, rather than spending ages creating the perfect proposal for *their* questions, only for the proposal to fail, since they don't have anything else to base it on.

Comment: @JasonC For example, (and I know that Stacks for these already exsist), if fans of Blues all got together for a Blues stack, that would likely be too narrow, encouraging a stack for each of the other Music genres. However, if lots of lost questions came under other genres of music the proposal creator might say in DiscussArea51, "Should I create a Blues stack or a Music stack?". It may, rather than meaning that a lot of the lost qs are closed, mean that fewer Area 51 proposals are pretty much closed before they get 5 people.

Comment: I understand that severe question clean-up is needed... I have an essay, when I could have a paragraph. I will try to do this while keeping the main ideas.

Comment: @wizzwizz2 Done... I think.

Comment: @ColleenV I think I have cleaned up the question so it is readable and concise.

Comment: You did a good job fixing up the proposal, but I'm still having trouble imagining the sorts of questions involved. Are there some examples of "lost" questions? I haven't seen a *good* question that needs a site proposal (that doesn't mean they don't exist though) Mostly I see questions that aren't a good fit for the SE format or queries for where someone can ask about a particular topic.

Comment: @JasonC I've cleaned up my question / utterly changed it to fit the idea I had in my head better, but it's already attracted so many downvotes that it is relatively impossible to show anyone it (without them automatically assuming that the new edit was the original thing I asked and therefore "not what the community wants") See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296738/327239 . If I re-ask it will be closed as a duplicate of my original question... I appear to have reached an impassable situation... Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Not a response to your previous comment, but fyi, [this tangentially related thing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110234/useless-faq) just popped up on Area 51. Also there is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s), not sure if that was linked above already.

Comment: As for what you should do about this, well... that's a good question. I *feel* like maybe you should rollback to your previous revision (which Caleb's answer below is addressing, btw), wait a few days for folks to forget about this post (you can't, and probably shouldn't, delete this), then try again from scratch in a new post. Disclaimer: No idea how well that will actually go over, but that's my gut, fwiw. The recent change is very drastic.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks! I'll try that and wait to see what happens.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the version I actually answered (#14). Your #15 is a completely different beast and not well suited to being in the same post. Asking if something is an issue and whether it should be fixed is different than proposing a detailed solution. Please don't put them in the same question. If anything that content would be something you post _as an answer_ to this question that details why you think it should be fixed and  what specifics would make it work.

Comment: @Caleb #15 was originally #11, what was originally there. I agree that they should not be in the same post, which is why I rolled back, see directly above in comments and the linked Meta post, the one you answered.

Comment: @JasonC Should I re-roll back, or leave it be to avoid edit-warring?

Comment: @wizzwizz2 I have no good advice for you, sorry. Do whatever you think makes sense. I wouldn't overthink it.

Comment: Well... maybe one day I'll be able to explain it well, perhaps when I have more Stack experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this sounds like a good idea. It's far too complicated for too little potential benefit. There is already much confusion surrounding the very notion of off-topic questions, and then you have Area 51 where people cannot seem to get the hand of not answering *sample* questions. This seems like it would just clutter things up even more.

Also, who would it really serve? The people asking the questions that get stuck in limbo without a site to host their question aren't going to be helped. If they are interested in a site proposal Area 51 is a good place to channel their interest, but they won't get gratified by topical questions right away (not for months or years until a site proposal goes through). I also don't think the site definition process will be expedited by having some holding ground for previously off-topic questions. The existing system of parsing such candidate questions down to just a title as a sample seems better in the long run.

Comment: They will be helped, eventually, and for those who are prepared to ask on Meta, they don't want a rushed/quick answer to their question, they usually want others to benefit from it. And if their few questions in limbo help others, and create a site where their future similar questions can be asked, that isn't a bad thing... is it?

Comment: It would serve others,and those creating/helping with proposals. And just a question title won't help if a good well formatted question can be made in the site's name. This could prevent "Could this site *really* produce good questions?" questions, stop the flood of 1-5 person proposals (as they could tell if anyone shared their view), and help an early definition site gain traction. I'll just find some examples...

Comment: Some examples of 1-5 person proposals: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110134/miniature-painting http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109933/grateful-dead http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109914/book-recommendations http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109892/microsoft-office

Comment: And these are ones that could just be stopped by a tiny, simple process in the middle. What is a great shame is A51 proposals being stopped because even though they are popular, they are stopped as dupe, or even though they are very well thought out, there is not yet the people for them. These people then often either then leave empty-handed and leave the idea, perhaps even the community (if that was to be their first site), more importantly, the community doesn't get built.

Comment: And if they have a good question that they have, whether or not it will be answered, they may much rather to have it here waiting, in order to help build a community, than on our hyphenated-friends, or left to be trolled and misused by *generic-search-engine* Answers.

Comment: The entire purpose of this site is to house good-quality off-topic questions, showing others the difference between off-topic and bad question, and *improving* the quality of Area 51 example questions.